# Disable the Saros welcom pagee

Tags: eclipse, plugins

So I installed Saros in my eclipse and really like the tool. However the welcome page opens every single time I open Eclipse, is there a way to disable this? It doesn't seem to have any glaring or obvious way to disable the saros welcome on start up. Maybe I am just missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must configure your XMPP account in Saros setting. After this, 'Welcome page' will not be displayed anymore.